# How to create optimal query?

Tags: c#, linq, self-join

I have a list of menu items in database, like:

```
ID      ParentID      ItemOrder      Name
-------------------------------------------------------    
 1       null               1        Main_1
 2       null               2        Main_2
 3       null               3        Main_3
 4       null               4        Main_4
 5       null               5        Main_5
 6       1                  4        SubMenu_1.4
 7       1                  5        SubMenu_1.5
 8       1                  8        SubMenu_1.8
 9       2                  1        SubMenu_2.1
10       3                  1        SubMenu_3.1
11       3                  2        SubMenu_3.2
12       3                  4        SubMenu_3.4
```

`Submenu ItemOrder` may not necessarily start at 1, it may begin with a 3, and the following menu item order can be 7 and so on.

How to create linq query or lambda expression that will return all parent (zero level) menu items and their first child (if exists)?

Expected result:

```
ID      ParentID      ItemOrder      Name
-------------------------------------------------    
 1       null             1          Main_1
 2       null             2          Main_2
 3       null             3          Main_3
 4       null             4          Main_4
 5       null             5          Main_5
 6       1                4          SubMenu_1.4
 9       2                1          SubMenu_2.1
10       3                1          SubMenu_3.1
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! That way, you don't need any of those really really messy `&nbsp;` and `<br/>` tags anymore, either!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var items = dbContext.Table
    .Where(item => item.ParentID == null)
    .Union(dbContext.Table
        .Where(x => x.ParentID != null)
        .GroupBy(x => x.ParentID)
        .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault()));
```

Comment: This answer is correct but I think you need to use FirstOrDefault instead of First

Comment: @MVCKarl, there is no need to use `FirstOrDefault` - if there are no items with, let's say `ParentID == 3` then there will be no group with `Key == 3`. In other words each group will have at least one element.

Comment: This gives me `NotSupportedException` due to the use of `First` instead of `FirstOrDefault`. There's a missing bracket as well. And I think the values are not sorted which is required.

Comment: @SergeBelov, @MVCKarl - I have edited the code to use `FirstOrDefault()`. Thank you guys for pointing out the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
public IQueryable<MenuItem> MakeQuery()
{

    var parentsQuery =
        from parent in ctx.MenuItem
        where parent.ParentID == null
        orderby parent.ItemOrder
        select parent;

    var childrenQuery =
        from parent in parentsQuery
        join child in ctx.MenuItem
            on parent.ID equals child.ParentID
        where !ctx.MenuItem.Any(child2 => child2.ParentID == parent.ID
            && child2.ItemOrder < child.ItemOrder)
        orderby child.ItemOrder
        select child;

    return parentsQuery.Concat(childrenQuery);
}
```

This avoids the error "Types in Union or Concat are constructed incompatibly." from LINQ to SQL, and will only return the first-level children.

Comment: I think your answer more better, because there is direct link to parent. I'll try your version later.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use this query

```
    var parents = table.Where(i => i.ParentID == null);
    var immediateChildren = table
        .GroupBy(i => i.ParentID)
        .Select(g => g.OrderBy(i => i.ItemOrder).FirstOrDefault());
    var result = parents.Union(immediateChildren);
```

The results includes only immediate children as requested and variables help understand what's going on.

Comment: This is my first question on stackoverflow. Thanks to all who responded. RePierre answered first, but I think the answer Markus Jarderot more correct. I am not good in linq, so I will try to use all version and test their performance.